# Calculate the value of e^x

Tags: c, sum, infinite-loop, precision

[image]

I need to calculate the value of e^x. The loop is infinity and should stop when i get the precision 0.001, but i do not know how to get this precision.

```
float exp(float x){
    float ex=1,precision=0.000,powX=1.0,fat=1.0;
    int partInt;
    int i,j;
    for(i=1; precision!= 0.001; i++){
        for(j=1; j<=i; j++){
            powX *= x;
            fat *=j;
        }
        ex += powX/fat;
        partInt = ex;             // like a cast to integer
        precision= ex - partInt; // get the precision
        //printf("%f %f %f %f\n",powX,fat,precision,ex);
        powX = fat = 1.0;
    }
    return ex;
}


int main(){
    printf("%f",exp(2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's unlikely the precision is going to be *exactly* equal to `0.001`, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `double prev` to keep track of the result produced by the previous iteration. Stop when `abs(prev - ex) < precision`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `precision` is always `0` when checked, because you assign `ex`'s value to `partInt`, and then subtract them.

You can store each loop's result in a variable, and then compare it to the next loop's result. When their difference is *less* than `0.001`, stop the loop.